# __init__ with function as parameter (using the NetworkX)

Tags: python, oop, networkx

**The Question**

I want to be able to initialize an object with a function that references the instance's attributes.  What I want I tried to capture in this snippet, which produces a `NameError: "global name 'self' is not defined"`:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, function = None):
        self.dicty = {1:{'height': 4, 'width': 2}, 2:{'height': 1, 'width': 2} }
        if function == None:
            self.function = lambda x : self.dicty[x]['height']
        else:
            self.function = function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def func1(x):
        return self.dicty[x]['width']
    def func2(x):
        return self.dicty[x]['width']**2
    G = Test(function = func1)
    H = Test(function = func2)
```

I could solve the problem by creating a bunch of subclasses to `Test`, but that doesn't seem readable.

**The Motivation**

I am using NetworkX to do Python modeling and experiments.  I was looking at the classic [Albert-Barabasi Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model) and creating subclasses of the DiGraph class that included a `Preference(self, node)`, `Attachment(self, parent, child)`, and then a `Grow(self, max_allowable_nodes)`.  Instead of creating a whole bunch of subclasses like I mentioned before, I would love to be able to create an instance that modifies `preference()`. This would  allow me to run numerical experiments without my code looking too much like Frankenstein.  Looking forward to learning something new.

**Edit:**

Didn't know about the `types` class or the general idea of *reflection*.  Obviously, still pretty new here.  Really appreciate everyone answering my questions and pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Post the full traceback of the error. (Also your indentation for the contents of the `Test` class is off.)

Comment: `self` is not a magic keyword in python. You can't use a `self` object in a function that doesn't take one as a parameter.

Comment: You might consider using less software engineering (unless that is your goal).  The NetworkX Barabasi-Albert graph generator code is only about 10-20 lines of Python http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/generators/random_graphs.html#barabasi_albert_graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the `lambda` you create in your `__init__` refers to the instance (`self`), it looks like you want to attach a *method* to your instance, whereas here you're attaching a *function*. You need to create a method from the function and attach it to the instance:

```
import types

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, function = None):
        self.dicty = {1:{'height': 4, 'width': 2}, 2:{'height': 1, 'width': 2} }
        if function == None:
            function = lambda self, x: self.dicty[x]['height']
        self.function = types.MethodType(function, self)
```

A method is basically a function that is *always* passed the instance as the first argument, so you need to ensure any function you pass into your initialiser has `self` as the initial argument.

```
>>> t1 = Test()
>>> t1.function(1)
4

>>> t2 = Test(lambda self, x: self.dicty[x]['width'])
>>> t2.function(1)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define `func1`, there is no such thing as `self`. It's not an argument to the function, and it's not in any higher scope.

You could, instead, define a function that takes the `dict` you use as an argument and operates on that. In the `Test` class, you can then call the function on `self.dicty`. This would require you to change your `lambda` to also take `dicty` and `x` instead of just `x`.

```
def func1(dicty, x):
    return dicty[x]['width']
```

...and in `Test`...

```
class Test(object):

    # ... current code but with lambda tweak:
    # lambda dicty, x: dicty[x]['height']

    def do_something(self, x):
        self.function(self.dicty, x)
```

Without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to know what further simplifications you could make. But since all the functions seem to be using `dicty[x]` anyway, you could just write them to take that directly.